# Vector subscription out of range, how do I eliminate this error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, vector

That's the code:

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <cmath>
  using namespace std;
  inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }


  int main()
  {
      string name = "lol";
      int score = 0;
      vector<string>names;
      vector<int>scores;
      bool choose = true;
      for (int l = 0; name != "stop"; ++l) {
          cin >> name >> score;
          if (name == names[l]) choose = false;
          if (choose == true) {
              names.push_back(name);
              scores.push_back(score);
          }
          else cout << "error, name already used" << endl;
          choose = true;


      }


  }
```

When I run the program, and I type a name followed by a score, it says: "debug assertion failed: vector subscription out of range".
Why? And how do I eliminate this error?

Comment: Don't try to access an element of the vector that doesn't exist.

Comment: If you step through this code in a debugger, you should be able to find the problem

Comment: Your bug is here `if (name == names[l]) choose = false;` when this is called `names[l]` is not valid. It will have at most (l -1 elements).

Comment: Look at the first iteration of the loop. Notice that you're unconditionally reading from `names`. How many elements does the vector have at this point?

Comment: When you first start using `std::vector` use `at` instead of `[]`.  That will help you find these problems.

Comment: Upon the first iteration, your `names` array is empty, thus `names[0]` doesn't have any value it (it may not even exist).

Comment: @Daniele De Blu, What about this issue? I test it using Michał Kalinowski's suggestion, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You try get element that doesn't exist. First you need push something to

```
  vector<string> names;
```

or do check if names is empty:

```
if (!names.empty())
    if(name == names[l])
        choose = false;
```

also looking what you want achieve, it's seems that you have anyway wrong code, you only look at the last name you have added. So to help you a bit this solution works better:

```
int main()
{
    string name;
    vector<string> names;

    while (cin >> name && name != "stop")
    {
        bool choose = true;

        for (auto i : names)
        {
            if (name == i)
                choose = false;
        }
        if (choose)
        {
            names.push_back(name);
        }
        else cout << "error, name already used" << endl;
    }
}
```